# An alternative proof of Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let's focus on the following version of Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem:

> **Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem**: Let $f, g$ be functions defined on closed interval $[a, b]$ such that
>
> 1) Both $f, g$ are continuous on $[a, b]$
>
> 2) Both $f, g$ are differentiable on $(a, b)$
>
> 3) $g'$ does not vanish at any point in $(a, b)$
>
> then there is a point $c \in (a, b)$ such that $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$

In most *good textbooks* it is mentioned that this theorem can't be derived from the usual Mean Value Theorem. Using MVT we can get $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)} = \frac{(f(b) - f(a))/(b - a)}{(g(b) - g(a))/(b - a)} = \frac{f'(c_{1})}{g'(c_{2})}$$ and we can't guarantee that $c_{1} = c_{2}$ and hence the above strategy to prove Cauchy's theorem fails.

However I beg to differ and I provide the following argument. The geometrical interpretation of MVT is that *if we take any two points on a continuous and smooth curve (with some further restrictions on nature of curve) then between this portion of the curve there is a point at which the tangent to the curve is parallel to the chord joining these two points*. Cauchy's theorem is obtained at once if we use the parametric equation of the curve with $x = g(t), y = f(t), dy/dx = f'(t)/g'(t)$ for $t \in (a, b) $ and the endpoints of the curve are $(g(a), f(a)), (g(b), f(b))$. Hence Cauchy's Theorem is derivable from MVT.

The rigorous proof proceeds as follows. Since $g'$ does not vanish it is clear from Rolle's theorem that $g$ is one one function so that $g(a) \neq g(b)$. If $g(a) < g(b)$ then we can show that $g$ is strictly increasing. Let $a \leq c < d \leq b$. Clearly $g(c) \neq g(d) \neq g(a)$. Let us suppose $g(d) < g(a)$ so that $g(d) < g(a) < g(b)$ and hence by IVT there will be a point $x$ in $(d, b)$ with $g(x) = g(a)$ contrary to the fact that $g$ is one one. So we must have $g(a) < g(d)$. Similarly $g(c) < g(b)$. Now suppose that $g(c) > g(d)$ so that $g(a) < g(d) < g(c)$ and by IVT there is an $x \in (a, c)$ with $g(x) = g(d)$ contrary to the fact that $f$ is one one. Hence $g(c) < g(d)$. We have thus shown that $g$ is strictly increasing. If $g(a) > g(b)$ then we can show in same manner that $g$ is strictly decreasing.

Hence by inverse function theorem $h = g^{-1}$ exists and is continuous and differentiable. Suppose $g$ is increasing and let $A = g(a), B = g(b)$ so that $a = h(A), b = h(B)$ and consider the function $F(x) = f(h(x))$ on $[A, B]$. By MVT there is a $C \in (A, B)$ such that $$F(B) - F(A) = (B - A)F'(C)$$ or $$f(h(B)) - f(h(A)) = (g(b) - g(a))f'(h(C))h'(C)$$ If $h(C) = c$ then $c \in (a, b)$ and $h'(C) = 1/g'(c)$ and we get $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$

> I would like to get feedback on this proof above. I haven't found any issue with the argument and think it is perfectly valid.

Comment: Looks nice, although if you would spell out the first part of the argument ($g$ is strictly monotonic), the "usual" argument would win in brevity.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the argument http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290172/geometrical-interpertation-of-cauchys-mean-value-theorem?rq=1

Comment: @PhoemueX: Edited my post to include proof of monotone nature of $g$.

Comment: @A.G.: I checked the linked question and it appears that it repeats the same geometric arguments which I have mentioned in my post. I have tried to make that argument more rigorous by using properties of continuous/differentiable functions. A geometric intuition can't be substitute for a rigorous proof.

Comment: Your approach is legal: it is found in T. Flett _Differential analysis_ (1980), pp.16-17 . Flett uses this argument to show that Cauchy's theorem is essentially a particular case of Lagrange's !

Comment: "In most good textbooks it is mentioned that this theorem can't be derived from the usual Mean Value Theorem." Of course it can; that's what the short proof does. I think what you mean is one's first stab at a proof, using the MVT, is likely to fail.

Comment: @zhw.: yes that's what i meant... thanks for making this explicit.

Comment: Fine,except for a trivial typo in the  first line,where dy/dx is defined for t in [a,b], which should be (a,b).

Comment: To those who are sufficiently experienced  in some of the basics, the assertion that $h=g^{-1}$ exists, is continuous on $[a,b],$ and  differentiable on $(a,b)$, can be  stated without proof.. Nice proof, altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Or we could just consider the function:

$F(x)=f(x)-f(a)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}(g(x)-g(a))$

Clearly $F(x)$ is defined iff $g(b) $  is different from $g(a)$ , otherwise if $g(a)=g(b)$ then $F(x)$ would satisfy Role's theorem's conditions hence there would exist a point $c$ $ \epsilon$ $(a,b)$ such that $g'(c)=0$ this is a contradiction to our third condition :

> 3) $g'$ does not vanish at any point in $(a, b)$

Then from the MVT we have :

There exists a point $c$ $\epsilon$ $(a,b)$ such that $F'(c)=0$

thus we get :

$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}g'(c)$

or

$\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}$

Comment: This is the standard proof which most textbooks present. My question was not about it, but rather about the validity of the alternative proof given in my post.