# Mean Value Theorem, Indeterminate forms and L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus

[image]

I had my own doubts about the above equation. So I plotted a few graphs. I have taken $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) =e^x - 1$. I have chosen $a=-1$ and $b=1$. Below, are the two graphs I have plotted.

[image]

Here, $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} =0$. Mean Value Theorem gives us $C_1=0$.

[image]

Above, $\frac{g(b) - g(a)}{b-a} =1.1751$. Mean Value Theorem gives us $C_2=0.1613$. Clearly, $C_1\neq C_2$. The equation in general can be written as, $$\frac{f'(C_1)}{g'(C_2)} = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)} \neq \frac{f'(C_1)}{g'(C_1)}(or) \frac{f'(C_2)}{g'(C_2)} $$

The proof of L'Hospital's rule was worked out using the equation $\frac{f'(C)}{g'(C)} = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)}$. It does not convince me to a good extent. Am I missing a point here, thereby complicating the work?

---

I went ahead and tried approaching the proof of L'Hospital's rule in a different way. If the below proof is right, then I'm quite sure that it is not a new way of approach.

Given, functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and differentiable in an interval containing a point $a$. The two functions take zero values at $a$, say. We have, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. This limit, at first look, takes an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. An indeterminate form can take any value( or no value ). We can write, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)h}{g(x)h}$$ Where $h\neq0$. Further we can write, $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{(f(a+h)-f(a-h))2h}{(g(a+h)-g(a-h))2h}$$ Where once again the limit takes the same indeterminate form. Mean Value Theorem gives us, $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(C_1)}{g'(C_2)}$$

As $h$ gets close to zero, $C_1$ and $C_2$ get close to $a$. We can then write, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}= \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Here, we assume that $g'(x) \neq 0$.

Could there be any flaw in this approach?

Comment: You say you plotted $x^2$ and $e^x-1$, but then below is the plot of $x^2$ and $1$. Please clean up your question, it's very confusing.

Comment: The equations you see other than the functions are secants derived from the Mean Value Theorem. Did I clear it for you?

Comment: Everything is color coded. That should clear any confusion, I'm hoping.

Comment: Yes, there's a flaw: how do you prove that if$x$ and $y$ approach $a$, the limit of $f'(x)/g'(y)$ is the same (if it exists!) as the limit of $f'x)/g'(x)$?

Comment: Using the Sandwich Theorem. We have, $a-h<C_1<a+h$; $a-h<C_2<a+h$. As $h\rightarrow 0$, $C_1,C_2 \rightarrow a$.

Comment: The paragraph after the second plot makes no sense to me (as well as the second plot itself).  Also, why are you looking at $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ and  $\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}$ respectively, as opposed to  $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}$? What are the function $f$ and $g$ in the second plot?

Comment: The first plot is for $f(x)$ while the second is for $g(x)$. The color codes indicate the functions and the secants( derived from Mean Value Theorem ).

Comment: Let me explain the plots.

Comment: The first plot is of $f(x) = x^2$. The line $y=1$ is the secant whose slope is zero. We see that the secant goes through $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$, where $b=1$ and $a=-1$. Mean value theorem tells us that there is a point between $b$ and $a$, a point $C_1$, where $f'(C_1) =0$. That point in the plot is $C_1=0$. In the second plot, considering the same $b$ and $a$, I see that $g(b) - g(a) \neq 0$ but $1.1751$. Mean Value Theorem tells us that there is a point in $(a, b) $, $C_2$, where $g'(C_2) = 1.1751$. That $C_2$ is $0.1613$. I did all the calculations. Since $C_1\neq C_2$

Comment: We have, $\frac{f(C)}{g(C)} \neq\frac{f(C_1)}{g(C_2)}= \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)} $.

Comment: It appears that you are doubting the truth of Cauchy's MVT. It is better that you see the proof. Also understand that it can't be derived using MVT separately applied on $f, g$. See this question  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1380881/72031 for more details.

Comment: The second part dealing with L'Hospital's Rule does not seem to make much sense. The only way to link the expression $f/g$ with $f'/g'$ is via Cauchy's MVT. Your approach does get to $f'/g'$ but the arguments of $f', g'$ are different and then it is not guaranteed that limit of $f'(c_1)/g'(c_2)$ is same as that of $f'(c) /g'(c) $.

Comment: For your example $f, g$ we clearly have $f'(0)/g'(0)=(f(1)-f(-1))/(g(1)-g(-1))=0$ so that Cauchy's MVT is satisfied.

Comment: Yes. I seem to have gotten confused here. I need to rethink.

Comment: The explanation you have given in your post is brilliant. I initially did not believe in simply taking the ratio( on applying mean value theorem ) because my graphs did not agree.

Comment: In the text, Cauchy's Mean Value theorem was derived for a 'general curve'. The coordinates of this curve are of the form $(f(x), g(x))$. It seems like the then thought independent variable is now a function of $x$. If we make $g(x) =x$, we have Legrange's Mean Value Theorem in place. I find that Cauchy's theorem is a generalization. Later in the text, I will see how these general curves are formulated.

Comment: To a beginner, the ratio might seem to be established simply by 'directly' using Legrange's theorem. That was my case. The geometric interpretation of Cauchy's theorem, however, is more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you understand Mean Value Theorem (MVT) correctly (as far as I understood your question).

For $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ MVT gives us the following:

$\exists$ $c_1 \in [a, b]: f^{'}(c_1) = \dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$

$\exists$ $c_2 \in [a, b]: g^{'}(c_2) = \dfrac{g(b) - g(a)}{b - a}$

$\exists$ $c_3 \in [a, b]: \dfrac{f^{'}(c_3)}{g^{'}(c_3)} = \dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)}$

$c_1, c_2, c_3$ are not related in any way, and MVT gives us no information about the actual values of $c_1, c_2, c_3$, we only know that these points do exist. In addition, $c_1, c_2, c_3$ don't have to be unique.

Comment: For the above functions, where is any such $C_3$?

Comment: What do you mean? $c_3$ is some point $\in [a, b]$, such that this equality holds $\dfrac{f^{'}(c_3)}{g^{'}(c_3)} = \dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{g(b) - g(a)}$. We don't know where exactly on $[a, b]$ this point is located, we only know that it must exist.

Comment: I think, $\frac{f'(c_3)}{g'(c_3)}=\frac{\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}}{\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}} = \frac{f'(c_1)}{g'(c_2)}$. What does this tell us now?

Comment: Considering my functions, there is no such $c_3$.

Comment: For the functions $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = e^x - 1$, we are getting $\dfrac{f^{'}(c)}{g^{'}(c)} = \dfrac{1^2 - (-1)^2}{e^1 - e^{-1}} = 0$. Although in this case it is easy to see that $c = 0$, (since $f^{'}(0) = 0$), this is not the corollary of MVT, MVT gives us no information about the value of $c$.

Comment: $\dfrac{f^{'}(c_3)}{g^{'}(c_3)} = \dfrac{f^{'}(c_1)}{g^{'}(c_2)}$ doesn't give us any additional information, because it might be the case that $c_1 = c_2 = c_3$, or there could be other $c_1, c_2$ that satisfy this equation

Comment: I will need to rethink now. I seem to be confused here.